# Akaike Information Criterion I cannot interpret the result

Tags: regression, matlab, goodness-of-fit, aic

Maybe is a silly question, or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I've tried to implement AIC criterion to estimate the optimum number of parameters using Auto Regressive (AR) linear models using white noise as input.
$$AIC(p) = N\log(RSS) + 2p,$$
where $N$ is the number of observations and $RSS$ the residuals sum of squares.
The results does not really make sense to me: since the predictors variables are completely indipendent, I would expect an increasing values of aic, so why do I see such a large oscillations?     [image: AIC]

```
x = randn(100000,1);  % Generate white noise
for p = 1:30; 
    Z = [];
    for z = 1:p;                            % Here I build the predictors variables
        Z = horzcat(Z, x(z:end-p-1+z));
    end
    [b,bint,r] = regress(x(p+1:end),Z);     % Linear Regression
    aic(p) = N*log(sum(r.^2)/N) + 2*(p+2);  
    
end
```

Comment: By what measure are these oscillations "large"?  To me, they look consistent with purely random fluctuations attributable to the fact that the *data* will not be completely uncorrelated.

Comment: What I don't understand is that I expect the penalty term $2p$ should push the value upwards for high values of $p$. With "large oscillation" I mean deviation from the up trend which I expect. I repeat the simulation and every time it shows a similar pattern. I expect that AIC(p) should be minimized for very small values of $p$ with white noise.

Comment: @whuber data should be uncorrelated : they are generated from an autoregressive model of order 0 (i.e. they are just white noise). So adding parameters to the autoregressive models fitted on the data should not increase their likelihood.

Comment: @Camille Because the data are random, they are almost certain to exhibit a little bit of correlation: check it out yourself.

Comment: @whuber I agree, but we would expect the gain in likelihood to be small compared to the penalty due to adding an extra free parameter, since data are generated with p=0 and not p=1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most probable reason is that the AIC is not suited for this task. The Akaike Information Criterion and the Bayesian Information Criterion are two criteria for model comparison and selection, which are respectively defined as

$$
AIC  = -2\log( \hat{L} )+ 2p
$$
and
$$
BIC  = -2\log( \hat{L} )+ \log(N)p
$$

where $N$ is the number of data points. Although they differ in the way they are derived, we can consider, for this specific application, that they only differ in the way they penalize the number of free parameters $p$ in a model. A good reference on the differences between the AIC and the BIC is the following one :

Burnham, K. P., & Anderson, D. R. (2004). Multimodel inference: understanding AIC and BIC in model selection. Sociological methods & research, 33(2), 261-304.

In the tapering-effects context (that is to say when your family of models shows a continuous increase of complexity), which is illustrated in Fig. 1 of the paper, AIC will perform better than the BIC. On the other hand, when you only have a few big effects (i.e. when there is a big jump in complexity when you rank your models by increasing complexity), which is illustrated in Fig. 2, the BIC should be favored.

Here, you are clearly in the latter case. An autoregressive model with $p=0$ implies that your data are uncorrelated and corresponds to white noise. Any model with $p > 0$ implies a temporal correlation between your data. So there is a big jump in complexity between $p = 0$ and $p=1$, but not so much between $p=1$ and any other strictly positive value of $p$.

Using the BIC instead of the AIC thus allows to meaningfully compare your models :

[image]

Comment: Ok so maybe that happen because I am not testing the **real** model, which is $p=0$. I have come to the idea that the root of the problem is that AIC (as opposed to BIC) does not give enough penalty in the parameter term when there is very small or no information, and in this sense is not suited for the task.

Comment: Which is indeed what is stated in my answer ^^

Comment: thanks, also for the good reference, very helpful