# How to pick a "best" AIC for ARMA

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, aic

I'm just tackling time data for the first time. I'm looking at a data set of motor vehicle accidents in New York City between 2012-2020, and I want to run an ARMA on it. I read that a good way to select the order of the ARMA is to cycle through a number of orders and select the order with the lowest AIC/BIC.

To that effect, I created a for-loop. I started out going from 1 to 10, but when the AIC was still going down at 10 I increased the for-loop to 20:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARMA
for i in range(1,21):
    mod = ARMA(df['CRASH DATE'], order=(i,0))
    result = mod.fit()
    print('Order: {}\n    AIC: {}'.format(i, result.aic))
```

The AIC just bottomed out at the end of that:

```
Order: 1
    AIC: 108866399.92257941
Order: 2
    AIC: 108433358.66644885
Order: 3
    AIC: 108288092.19893424
Order: 4
    AIC: 108216112.6723161
Order: 5
    AIC: 108171087.71846458
Order: 6
    AIC: 108147230.39500903
Order: 7
    AIC: 108132522.26115902
Order: 8
    AIC: 108123262.98575883
Order: 9
    AIC: 108117833.0090298
Order: 10
    AIC: 108114902.99831836
Order: 11
    AIC: 108112122.48864862
Order: 12
    AIC: 108110574.15724374
Order: 13
    AIC: 108110002.72451176
Order: 14
    AIC: 108109249.71983375
Order: 15
    AIC: 108108442.70226601
Order: 16
    AIC: 108108018.44834785
Order: 17
    AIC: 108107886.31128818
Order: 18
    AIC: 108107316.62252694
Order: 19
    AIC: 108107318.4172797
Order: 20
    AIC: 108107310.2332786
```

Does it make sense to have an ARMA of (18,0)? Or am I interpreting that AIC incorrectly?

Comment: So you did not reach the end of the loop, or did you? 18 is not 20.

Comment: @Yehuda Welcome to Cross Validated ! You can have a look at this related question : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/493131/akaike-information-criterion-i-cannot-interpret-the-result/493214#493214

Comment: @RichardHardy I did notice that 20 was lower than 18, but I decided to ask about 18 since 19, at least, went back up.

Comment: I think that is an important difference from what you wrote. Bottoming out before the end of the loop vs. at the end of it gives different indications as to what might be going on.