# AIC - when not to use it?

Tags: model-evaluation, aic

I have been wondering, is there any case in which AIC should be avoided as the evaluation metric? I cannot really find anything but for the advantages - what about the disadvantages? I'm mostly interested in time series models - assuming it changes anything.

Comment: E.g., when you are confident that the true model is in the set of the models considered, there are good reasons to prefer the BIC, see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197112/why-information-criterion-not-adjusted-r2-are-used-to-select-appropriate-la/197237#197237

Comment: The AIC also performs better than the BIC in the tapering effect context, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/493214/271601

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AIC is asymptotically identical to leave-one-out cross-validation. Thus, you should use it any time you would use CV to select your model, which is mainly when you want to minimise predictive error.

The disadvantage is that in a limited data situation, AIC will not select the causal model, and in the large-data limit, AIC will select more complicated models than BIC, and is not necessarily asymptotically consistent if the true model is in the set.

I would say the bottomline is that AIC is a good criteria if you want to minimise predictive error in a data-limited situation.

Comment: Wouldn't AIC lead to overfitting in data-limited situation?

Comment: Why would you think so? I mean, for small data, you can use AICc, but in principle, I would say AIC is a metric that explicitly aims at avoiding overfitting in model predictions

Comment: Because AIC - as far as I know but I might be wrong here - tends to choose more complex models than BIC, which is what I find prone to overfitting

Comment: Yes, but differences between AIC and BIC get larger in the large-data limit, so this is in the large-data limit

Comment: Oh I didn't know that! So the results with AIC and BIC will more or less converge in small datasets?

Comment: BIC penalizes k log(n) and AIC with 2k, so AIC = BIC for data size n = exp(2) ~ 7.

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't think about it by myself! If you find a moment, please add it to your answer so the future generations can see it too :D